# calcular promedio de notas laravel

Tags: laravel

Tengo una tabla
Notas(id,id_matricula,id_evaluación,nota)

Por medio de mi controlador envio las notas de un alumno logeado a la vista:

```
public function calificaciones($id) 
{  
    $alumno = Alumno::find(auth('alumno')->user()->id);
    $asignatura = Asignatura::find($id);
    $evaluaciones = $asignatura->evaluaciones;
    $matricula = Matricula::where('id_alumno','=',$alumno->id)->get()->last();

    $notas = array();
    foreach ($asignatura->notas as $nota) 
    {
        if (!isset($notas[$nota->id_matricula]))
        {
            $notas[$nota->id_matricula] = array();
        }

        $notas[$nota->id_matricula][$nota->id_evaluacion] = $nota->nota;
    }


    return view('datos-alumno.calificaciones')->with('alumno',$alumno)->with('matricula',$matricula)->with('asignatura',$asignatura)->with('evaluaciones',$evaluaciones)->with('notas',$notas);
}
```

se ve de la siguiente manera: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es la vista:

```
<table class="table table-bordered">               
<tr>

    @foreach ($evaluaciones as $e)
      <th width="10">{{$e->nombre}} <a href="" data-target="#modal-show-{{ $e->id }}"" data-toggle="modal" class="btn-xs btn-info"> <span class="fa fa-info" aria-hidden="true"></span></a></th>
      @include('datos-alumno.modal') 
    @endforeach
  <th width="100">Promedio </th>
</tr>

<tr>

    @for($i=0, $length = count($evaluaciones); $i < $length; $i++)
      <td><input class="nota" disabled type="text" data-id-matricula="{{ $matricula->id }}" data-id-evaluacion="{{ $evaluaciones[$i]->id }}" value="{{ (isset($notas[$matricula->id]))? (isset($notas[$matricula->id][$evaluaciones[$i]->id]))?$notas[$matricula->id][$evaluaciones[$i]->id]: 1.0 : 1.0 }}"/></td>
    @endfor
  <td></td>
</tr>
```

Como podria hacerlo para calucular ese promedio? estuve intentando con

```
$promedio = DB::table('notas')
    ->select(sum('notas')/count($evaluaciones))
    ->where('id_matricula',$matricula->id)
    ->get();
```

Answer (score -1):

Puedes calcular el promedio en el `foreach` sumando las notas y al finalizar el `foreach` dividir la sumatoria entre el numero de evaluaciones y retornar el promedio a la vista. Se lo agregué a tu código pero no verifique que funcionara ya que no tengo las tablas. Espero que te sea de ayuda.

```
public function calificaciones($id)
{
    $alumno = Alumno::find(auth('alumno')->user()->id);
    $asignatura = Asignatura::find($id);
    $evaluaciones = $asignatura->evaluaciones;
    $matricula = Matricula::where('id_alumno','=',$alumno->id)->get()->last();

    $notas = array();
    $promedios = array();
    foreach ($asignatura->notas as $nota)
    {
        if (!isset($notas[$nota->id_matricula]))
        {
            $notas[$nota->id_matricula] = array();
        }

        $notas[$nota->id_matricula][$nota->id_evaluacion] = $nota->nota;

        if (!isset($promedios[$nota->id_matricula]))
        {
            $promedios[$nota->id_matricula]["promedio"] = 0;
            $promedios[$nota->id_matricula]["numero_evaluaciones"] = 0;
        }
        $promedios[$nota->id_matricula]["promedio"] += $nota->nota;
        $promedios[$nota->id_matricula]["numero_evaluaciones"]++;
    }


    foreach ($promedios as $key => $value)
    {
        $promedios[$key]["promedio"] /= $promedios[$key]["numero_evaluaciones"];
    }


    return view('datos-alumno.calificaciones')->with('alumno',$alumno)->with('matricula',$matricula)->with('asignatura',$asignatura)->with('evaluaciones',$evaluaciones)->with('notas',$notas)->with('promedios',$promedios);
}
```

Comment: Gracias por responder, pero  $promedio += $nota->nota; me esta sumando las notas de todos los alumnos en una evaluacion, si lo saco del for, me suma solo la ultima nota :(

Comment: Ya edite la respuesta. Asi puedes tener el promedio por el id_matricula.

Comment: Gracias ahora me esta mandando las notas y el numero de evaluaciones por asignatura, pero estoy perdido como puedo mostrarlos en la vista, como recorrerlos?